# What's the VS shortcut for type hierarchy?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the equivalent of eclipse's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> for Visual Studio?
Preferably no third party tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), although I'm not sure whether there's a shortcut key available in stock VS or not.